# Is there a way to reference response in swagger @ApiResponse from json or yml rather than a class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have the following annotation used in a controller:

```
@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "failed", response = MediaDataProductResponseV2.class)}
```

As you can see, the response string is displayed based on the class. How can you reference the response from a file like yml or json?

example

```
@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "failed", response = "${error}")} -> this doesn't work
```

The problem I have is that the company's code is including all the error and success objects in a single pojo so there is no way to segregate the type of response we send to our clients. Let's say we have the following pojo response:

```
public class pojo{
       private String error;
       private String response;
       … setters and getters...
    }
```

If something goes wrong we just return the error part. If success, the response. There is no way I can point that out in the annotations as it will always serialize the whole thing and I don't want to play around with the pojos as they they are generated from a json schema. I need to reference the response from something else that can't be a class.

Comment: Do you need to specifically do that in the annotation? It basically automatically infers from the return type of your method, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I will elaborate a little bit more on the reason to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Error-handling is a cross-cutting concern and hence should not be tangled with business logic. Therefore It would be better to have a seperate class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` that handles failures.

You then define a method that takes the *exception* and a `HttpServletRequest` as parameters and returns a `ResponseEntity` of a type that contains the error message you want to return.

This method is annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(myException.class)`. The exception itself is annotated with `@ResponseStatus(HTTPSTATUS.MYSTATUS)`. That way you have centralized your error-handling in one place while at the same time applying the error handling to all your controllers.

You can override this however by passing the `basePackageClasses` as an argument to the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation.